# Optimize image size in Parse.com

Tags: image-processing, parse-platform, image-resizing

I have a strange issue with the resize methods on Parse Image Module:
First I get an image of 3.8MB (1920x1080px) in a Parse Cloud Code, then I resize it to 384x216px.

What I can't figure out is that when I download the resulting image in my front application, the file size is still 3.8MB while the image size reduced as expected.

I can't allow myself to force my users to download images so heavy.

Any suggestions on how to solve this out ?

I am ready to work with an external library as long as it can be executed on Parse Cloud Code.

Answer (score 0):

Do not resize images in the cloud. Resize them on the client and send small files over the web. It takes shorter processing time to resize them in comparison to traveling over the network.

The reason you are seeing the old image in front of your application is probably because parse has an internal cache. Queries that have been sent before load from the cache to lower the amount of transferred data. You can easily observe this by deleting the application and reinstalling, your images will probably work fine.

http://blog.parse.com/2011/09/30/easy-caching-with-parse/
https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-caching/iOS